# iOS Simulator Rendering Issues At 50% Scale

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7

Once upon a time there was a developer who ran the iOS simulator at 50% scale so the simulator would fit on his MacBook Pro screen.  The simulator display rendered beautifully at this scale, and all was well.

One day, Apple unleashed xCode 7 with updated simulators.  Jagged lines ravaged the once smooth renderings of the simulators at 50% scale.  The chosen device mattered naught to the harsh pixelation.  Some UITableViewCell separators even fled the atrocity and would not return until the scale was increased to 75% or higher.  Likewise, at a 75% or higher scale, the crisp renderings of yore would return to the simulator.  But alas, a scale of such magnitude would not fit on the developer's screen and would summon the detested scroll bars.

The developer questioned his co-workers across the land; some noticed the issue while others did not.  It seemed not to matter whether the other devs' screens were retina displays.  The developer's quest has continued, seeking to restore the beauty and order that once was, but no longer is.

Can you help the young developer and his comrades?

Comment: ahaha. Sorry, I can't help. I have the same problem!

Comment: Add some steps you took to resolve. Did you resent the simulator or reinstall Xcode? Add more details about the config. What Specific version of: 1) Mac OS, 2) Xcode, 3) Simulator. I should note that some versions of the simulator only run under certain versions of the Mac OS. Does this occur with all versions of the Simulator or only a subset of the simulators?

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable this setting: "Debug > Optimize Rendering for Window Scale"

Answer (score 0):

All developers at our company also suffer from this. I strongly believe apple is deliberately doing this to update our mac books. We are using late 2012 mac book pro's in our office. I can find this issue on both 10.10.xx and 10.11.xx OS. It's mainly the XCode 7 that brought this issue.